# Free a Binary Tree & Count the number of free nodes -> without a global variable

Tags: c

In `int freeAB(ABin a)` the `a` is a pointer to the root of the tree. I have to free all the memory space occupied by it, returning the number of freed nodes. This is a binary search tree.

***Questions:*** If I don't initialize the `removeNodes` with 0 will it have the chance of initialize with a random number?

***Note:*** I know that I could do a function that counts all the leafs and then use this one to free everything. But I want to do all in one.

valor = value, pai = father, esq = left, dir = right.

```
typedef struct nodo {
int valor;
struct nodo *pai, *esq, *dir;
} *ABin;
```

**My Solution:**

```c
int freeAB(ABin a){
  int removeNodes;
  while(a != NULL){
    removeNodes++;
    freeAB(a->esq);
    removeNodes++;
    freeAB(a->dir);
    free(a->pai);
  }
  return removeNodes;
}
```

Comment: Total removed nodes for a subtree is `1+<removed from left subtree> + <removed from right subtree>`

Comment: Have you heard of preorder, inorder and postorder method of traversing through a tree? You can use the same methods to delete nodes too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a local variable is not initialized, it's value is *indeterminate*.  So using the `++` operator on `removeNodes` before it is given a value can trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  So you should initialize it to 0.

Regarding counting the nodes, you're recursively calling `freeAB` but never using the return value.  You need to add this return value to your current counter.

Also, `while(a != NULL)` doesn't make sense.  `a` is never changed inside of the loop, so if the loop is entered you have an infinite loop.  This should instead be an `if` statement.

You probably don't want to `free(a->pai)` if it points to the parent node since it's still being used in earlier recursive calls, so this should be removed.  You do however want to free the *current* node after you've traversed its children.

After applying these changes, your function should now look like this:

```
int freeAB(ABin a){
  int removeNodes = 0;
  if (a != NULL){
    removeNodes++;
    removeNodes += freeAB(a->esq);
    removeNodes += freeAB(a->dir);
    free(a);
  }
  return removeNodes;
}
```

Comment: but if you recall the function the progress of the removeNodes will be lost right?

Comment: @IvoLims Each time you call the function, it has it's own set of local variables.  Changing a value in one invocation of the function won't affect other invocations.

Comment: @IvoLims There is no "progress" in it, it is a temporary local variable you can completely remove by returning `1 + freeAB(a->esq) + freeAB(a->dir)` or `0` for `a==NULL`